# Disable scroll button until fully scrolled

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/ha26ktan/pen/oNoQGEO

I built a website with my minimal - intermediate level of css and html knowledge. I have 2 buttons. One of them is for scrolling to the right and the other to the left. This scrolling is according to the width of a divin column.

When the right or left button is pressed repeatedly, the command is triggered again without waiting for the distance to go, and this causes it to stay outside the required distance.

How can I disable both buttons until they switch to the other column? Thank you very much in advance.

```
`const kitapp = document.getElementById('kitapp');

document.getElementById("btnLeft").onclick = () => {
  kitapp.scroll({
    left: kitapp.scrollLeft + kitapp.querySelector(".deneme").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
     
document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = () => {
  kitapp.scroll({
    left: kitapp.scrollLeft - kitapp.querySelector(".deneme").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}`
```

---

```
const kitapp = document.getElementById('kitapp');

document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = () => {
document.getElementById("btnRight").disabled = true;
  kitapp.scroll({
    left: kitapp.scrollLeft + kitapp.querySelector(".deneme").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
setTimeout(enableButon1, 1000);

}
 
document.getElementById("btnLeft").onclick = () => {
document.getElementById("btnRight").disabled = true;
  kitapp.scroll({
    left: kitapp.scrollLeft - kitapp.querySelector(".deneme").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
setTimeout(enableButon2, 1000);
  
}

function enableButon1() {
     document.getElementById("btnLeft").disabled = false;
}
function enableButon1() {
    document.getElementById("btnRight").disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable the button once you click on it, you can use

```
document.getElementById("btnLeft").disabled = true;
```

once you click on it. It can look like this:

```
const kitapp = document.getElementById('kitapp');

document.getElementById("btnLeft").onclick = () => {
  kitapp.scroll({
    left: kitapp.scrollLeft + kitapp.querySelector(".deneme").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
document.getElementById("btnLeft").disabled = true;
}
 
document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = () => {
  kitapp.scroll({
    left: kitapp.scrollLeft - kitapp.querySelector(".deneme").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  document.getElementById("btnRight").disabled = true;
}
```

I think this should work for you, but you will need to enable the button later, making a timer for example, or enabling it when you click the other button.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for the incredibly fast response. I have added your code. After clicking the button, it is deactivated but stays that way.I want it to be disabled until the scroll is finished and then active again.

Comment: Hi there, i have one question. Does it now scroll to the place you want to? Or it just stops somewhere?

Comment: When I press the button, it goes where I want and stops.

Comment: So you need to enable the button when it finishes right?

Comment: Yes, it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try to make like this:
When you click on the button, you can disable it

```
const kitapp = document.getElementById('kitapp');

document.getElementById("btnLeft").onclick = () => {
document.getElementById("btnLeft").disabled = true;
  kitapp.scroll({
    left: kitapp.scrollLeft + kitapp.querySelector(".deneme").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
setTimeout(enableButon1, 1000);

}
 
document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = () => {
document.getElementById("btnRight").disabled = true;
  kitapp.scroll({
    left: kitapp.scrollLeft - kitapp.querySelector(".deneme").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
setTimeout(enableButon2, 1000);
  
}

function enableButon1() {
     document.getElementById("btnLeft").disabled = false;
}
function enableButon1() {
    document.getElementById("btnRight").disabled = false;
}
```

I hope this one works for you.

You can change the time it waits changing the value of `setTimeout(enableButon2, 1000);` and put the number you want to wait.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you. Thank you very much indeed, but it's the same as the first one you posted.

Comment: I made some changes in the code and updated the first message. We are about to get the effect I want. Here's what happened. When I pressed the right button, the button was disabled until the distance ran out, and then it became active again. The left button is still in a state that can be pressed repeatedly.

Comment: Don't want to interfere with your work. Depending on the distance traveled, the button does not become active again. It becomes active according to a certain time you define. This causes problems.

Comment: I added codepen link